# Split cells containing ALLCAPS words

Tags: excel

I have a `.csv` file containing a column "First + Last name". I'd like to split the cells to get 2 columns (First Name and Last name). In each cell, the last name is written ALLCAPS. So here is my file right now :

```
First + Last name
﻿-----------------------------
John DOE
Marie-Helen ANDRE-JACQUES
Jean-Claude DOE
```

And i'd like to split cells so i have :

```
First name               |  Last name
--------------------------------------------------
John                     |  DOE
Marie-Helen              |  ANDRE-JACQUES
Jean-Claude              |  DOE
```

How would i do this in excel (or numbers) ?

Comment: in your examples you can use Text to Columns on the data tab and split on the space.

Comment: If you are importing you CSV using Power Query, you can split that column by using Transform and then select to split by space, or character transition (or edit the m-code to split using the pattern of space followed by all upper case text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to solve this problem is to use the FLASH-FILL Function of Excel.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-flash-fill-in-excel-3f9bcf1e-db93-4890-94a0-1578341f73f7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US